# Spectral radiance unit conversion

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, spectroscopy, si-units

I have spectral radiance data in SRUs (spectral radiance units), as a function of wavelength:
$$a = \mu W cm^{-2} sr^{-1} nm^{-1} $$

However, I am working with software which requires my data in the form:
$$b=mWcm^{-2}sr^{-1}\mu m^{-1}$$

Are these two units are equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, $1\textrm{ mW}=1000\, \mu \textrm{W} $ and $1\,\mu\textrm{m}=1000\textrm{ nm}$, so that
$$
1\textrm{ mW}\,\textrm{cm}^{-2}\textrm{sr}^{-1}\mu\textrm{m}^{-1}=
1000\textrm{ mW}\,\textrm{cm}^{-2}\textrm{sr}^{-1}\left(1000\textrm{ nm}\right)^{-1}=
1 \,\mu\textrm{W}\,\textrm{cm}^{-2}\textrm{sr}^{-1}\textrm{nm}^{-1}
$$
and both units are exactly equivalent.